# How to Rerun the Failed Sessions Alone in a Workflow

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a WF which contains say 10 sessions. But only 6 out of 10 sessions got succeeded,
when i ran the WF. I need to run only the failed 4 sessions when i run the WF again, i shouldn't rerun the succeeded sessions. Please suggest to me how to achieve this.

NOTE: I AM USING THE SQLSERVER AS SOURCE AND ORACLE AS TARGET.

The same thread/Question is already present with some details not understanding properly

I tried the following

a) Define a parameter Restart_indicator (It can have 2 values 'Y' in Restart Situation, 'N' otherwise.

Que : How to give 2 values to the parameter (Parameter & variable in MAPPING Tool Bar)

b) Define a Run Table where work-flow name + session name will be the key.
c) At the start of workflow run initialize all entries associated with that work flow when Restart_indicator = 'N'
d) every time a session executes successfully , update the Run table entry for that workflow session combination.
e) For every session have a conditional execution the condition being
i) Restart_indicator = 'N'
or
Restart_indicator = 'Y' and Run_table entry for workflow session indicates that the session has not completed successfully.

QUE: How to define the conditional execution to begin the failed session to re-start? please elaborate this little bit.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This [post on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFjUMXDdvvU) gives a good explanation of how to conditionally start a session.

In your case, you would need to

1. create a workflow variable for each of the 10 sessions, make these persistent and initialize to 0
2. create a task after each session that updates it's corresponding workflow variable and set it's value to 1, this task should run only if the session completes successfully without error.
3. Before the session starts, you need to add a condition that checks that it's workflow variable is 0, only then start it.
4. In addition, you would need to add a task in the beginning of the workflow that would check all the 10 workflow variables (1 for each session) and if all are 1, then set all to 0. This will ensure that the next time you run the workflow it will start, even if all sessions completed successfully the previous time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks you for your prompt reply.. I have some query their

1. Will this workflow variable hold its value if I execute the WF after relogging (Means after 1-2 days)?
2. Point 3 - how/where to add a condition to check that WF variable.Means in SQ, in any Expression, lookup....

Comment: 1. You need to make the workflow variable persistent and then I think it will hold, see time 7:45 on video link that I sent, 2. Starting 8:11 onwards in the video you will see that the condition needs to be added to the link between the sessions. Hope this help. .

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind reply..
After each session i have to make another TASK(Assignmet TASK or dual session). for each session the assignment/session will also run means if i have 30 session it will run 60.
Is there anything in which i can do this check n play with Database table.
Hoping your best/prompt reply :)

Comment: You could track the session status in a database table using post-session commands, but even for that you will need to have a post-session to update the status and pre-session component to retrieve and check the status, and then start session conditionally..  all this assuming all 10 of your sessions run in parallel. Another option would be to "offload" some of these operations in your scheduler (e.g. Autosys, via Shell scripts) but that would be bigger design change..

Comment: Hi, I am doing the same now what you suggested 1st time. but stuck in 3rd point. if i will set the condition to check the WF variable =0 then it will never execute in succeeded case. May be i am missing something.

Comment: Check step 4. it addresses your concern